# ListView crashing the my application why?

Tags: android, listview

my app crashed when i try to scroll down in ListView I've tried to trace the error i couldn't find it , the activity works fine but when i try to scroll down the app getting crashed , could you please guys tell me where is the error or what i mess in my code ?

i had removed the scroll down effect and removed also

```
lv.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener()
```

but still same problem

listview xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background_scroller"
    >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/ringtoneListview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:background="@drawable/scrollback"
        android:divider="#93c7e8"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What is at line 105 in `Ringtones_Listview`?

Comment: yeh, its something (ClassCastsException) wrong inside your adapter which is not shown here.

Comment: thank you guys i just updated the question please take a look again

Comment: @JackKFouani: But we don't see the line number. Point it out in the OP.

Comment: at line 105 ( holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag(); )

Comment: @JackKFouani: You have implemented a `ViewHolder` class but aren't really using it in it's real sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you set an object to Long

```
convertView.setTag(r.getLong("toneid"))
```

and then you want this same object to be a View. ViewHolder (Type View)

```
holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
```

Comment: Correct i just removed the Long tag and its worked , but how i can set the view tag as Long number not integer ?

Comment: how to fix it what i have to change ? its work only when i remove convertView.setTag(r.getLong("toneid"))  , but i need to set the view tag as database toneid so i can call the toneid from anther class over the viewtag

Comment: Cast to long and a cast to Long are different. If you cast to long (a primitive value) then it should be automatically boxed to a Long (the reference type that wraps it).

You could alternatively use new to create an instance of Long, initializing it with the int value.

    Long.valueOf(int);

Comment: In Case, `Integer y = 1;
    long x = y.longValue();` OR 


`Long.valueOf(int);`